# Does Template 10 support Build 14393 SDK?

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I find this confusing: Anniversary Update, Redstone 1, Version 1607, and Build 14393. 
o.k I am now more confused. I started playing with Template 10 for universal app dev. Does template 10 support the 14393 SDK?

I am asking this because when I changed the target ver (from 10586) to 14393 I get different results. No doc to tell me if or not sdk 14393 is supported. If not supported, when will it support?

Comment: whoever down-voted my question, I wish they told me the reason. what a pity!

Comment: Probably downvoted, because this question lacks focus. It is essentially a one-liner, and you make us read through all your ramblings, and still don't come up with a concise question.

Comment: Does template 10 support the 14393 SDK? [Has a question mark at the end]

Comment: You would probably be better served by asking the Template10 devs directly.

Comment: Please ask the question so anyone can understand, then detail it so interested peers can get more info. Avoid exposing your feelings about it :)

Comment: @Amy - the template10 devs direct  Q&A to this site.

Comment: _"I get different results."_ - better or  worse? Vanilla or strawberry? That alone deserves a -1.

Comment: Ha ha! I get strawberry Holterman. Why some people are keen to be unhelpful -- i never understand.

Comment: @user2921851 No one here is "keen to be unhelpful".  Please keep things friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't support the newer features at present with that AU update, yet so the minimum support is 10240, fully supports 10586, expect to see a package in the future there will be dedicated to 14393 and some package separations based on the work items in the repository.  When in doubt directly checking the repository would have better results.

AU Library Milestone: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/milestone/9

Comment: Thank u. You meant 14393? Ok i now know why some sample don't work. do u know what template10 lacks to support the sdk? simple pointers pls.